# add java applet to php

Tags: php, html, applet

I'm trying to add java applet to my php code really I'm trying but still have the same error that the applet and the .jar not found can any one give me hello world example for that issue.

Comment: Given I am not psychic & I loaned out my crystal ball.  1) What is the HTML being used (paste it to the forum using code formatting)?  2)  What is the directory structure of the server?  AKA 'where is the HTML, Jar & applet?' 3) What is the exact **copy/pasted** error message?

Answer (score 1):

Rather that using applet tag look into using object tag instead. Applet is deprecated and isn't supported by all browsers.

And yeah, you don't need any PHP. It's HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

See [Embedding an Applet in an HTML Page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html#plugin). PHP is not involved.

Comment: Does you mean that PHP is not allowed? or not involved in that example?

Comment: PHP is separate. You do not need it in order to use an applet, unless the applet was specifically designed to communicate with the web-server somehow.